# React Native android Build Failing

Tags: android, react-native

In my react native app, I'm getting following build failed error after running npm run-android command.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-screens'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-screens:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-screens
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.2/gradle-4.2.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.2/gradle-4.2.2.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have installed 'react-native-screens" ? If not you need to install it.

Comment: It already installed